# How do I change .zip to .mcpack or .mcworld on iOS?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

In *Minecraft: Pocket Edition*, you can download `.mcpacks` to automatically open them and import them into *Minecraft*. I was wondering if there was a way to download ZIP files, then load them into *Minecraft* as a `.mcpack` or `.mcworld`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can change `.zip` files to `.mcpack` or `.mcworld`, because ZIP files and mcpack/mcworld files are both zipped files. All you have to do is change the file name extension on your PC.

Here is an answer that I found by someone else about the same question [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230605230314/https://old.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/59xaop/016_beta_addon_zip_to_mcpack_without_the_game/):

> The `.mcpack` is just a new extension name for a ZIP file. Make sure to have "View → File Name Extensions" turned on in Windows Explorer when changing the file extensions. Also to make working `.mcpack` files, you'll need to create the `manifest.json` correctly. There are a few other points.

So just change the file ending while the file is on your PC, then when your iOS device gets it, open it like you would normally. You can also get file managers from the Apple App Store to edit it.

Answer (score -1):

Download any file explorer and find the .zip file then just rename it to .mcpack

Answer (score -3):

Its easy. First you download Document 5 in App Store. Then, you rename the .zip into .mcpack. Lastly, you click open in -> minecraft

Comment: What exactly does Document 5 do?

Comment: Does it also work with .mcWorld?

Comment: Minecraft crashes when I try this