# How do I turn an MCPE world into a .mcworld file?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I have this map that I want to upload on MCPEDL, but in order to do so, I need to convert the world to an .mcworld file. I have no idea how to do this, however.

I have found nothing on the internet and the MCPEDL team has not responded to my 2 week old email. If it helps, I am using MCPE v1.4.0, on an iPad model A1566, running iOS 11.3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution step by step:

1. MCPE version has to be at least 0.16.
2. With a file explorer for iOS, find where your map is located on your device. It should be located at something like "games/mojang/minecraftworlds/yourWorldName".
3. Open that folder, select all content (not other folders, only file content), and zip them, giving the name of your world.
4. Rename the archive from "yourWorldName.zip" to "yourWorldName.mcworld".
5. Done. You can now upload it to MCPEDL, as it is openable by any device.

If you managed to have your world on a computer, you can change the file extension from there too (as proposed by many solutions on the web). .mcworld is a zipped type of file too.

Sources:

- [Reddit post on renaming archive](https://www.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/59pvm3/zip_to_mcworld/)
- [Android tutorial for renaming archive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6LlJFOX2qU)
- [iOS tutorial for saving worlds](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-multiplayer/mcpe-servers/2669568-transferring-a-minecraft-pe-world-from-iphone-to)
- [Arqade answer on a similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294171/how-to-change-zip-to-mcpack-on-ios)

Comment: Would the “Files” app work?

Comment: He means something which has root access to the main files that the iPhone uses. These aren't accessible normally. The "Files" app doesn't do that

Comment: Darn. Ok thanks anyways. I will get such an app and follow this procedure.